# Copying array but not increasing memory use

Tags: matlab, memory, struct

This is sort of a weird question but hopefully someone will be able to help me. 
I have a matlab code where due to the parallelized nature of the code i need to work with struct arrays.

After running the parfor loop I want to transform those structure arrays into three-dimensional arrays.

At the moment I am using the following code:

```
for k = 1:nsim
    ksim(:,:,k) = st(k).ksim;
    Msim(:,k) = st(k).Msim;
    Vsim(:,:,k) = st(k).Vsim;
    Psim(:,:,k) = st(k).Psim;
end
clearvars st
```

However this seems to be extremely inefficient as momentarily  matlab needs to double all the matrices thus almos doubling memory use. 
Any smarter way of achieving this without increasing that much memory use?

Comment: Why can't you leave the data as a struct?

Comment: Why must you use structures?  I would assume that you could preallocate your output and then populate it within the parallel portion.  Perhaps you could share details about that part.

Comment: If I don't use struct the matrices are 3 dimensional A(i,j,k) , where k is the paralellized dimension. Parfor cannot work with these. On the other hand if I make struct(k).A(i,j) it works perfectly.

Comment: @volcompt that's not true. `o = zeros(3,3,12);
parfor x = 1:12
o(:,:,x) = (-10 * input(x)) + (20 * input(x)) * rand(3);
end` works just fine.

Comment: you could vectorize by `ksim = [st(:).ksim]` and then `reshape` to regain the original format. if memory usage is a concern, you can then use `rmfield` to delete the `ksim` field from `st`.

Comment: Copying something typically takes twice the memory, unless you just copy something without modifying it (here I am talking real trivial as `a=b`, since MATLAB uses copy-on-write). This is kind of the point with copying, that you want a copy. MATLAB does not support move semantics. I would think that the best you can do is to remove the fields when you are done with them.

Answer (score 0):

I do not consider this as the answer you are looking for; But it is an improvement.

Define the new arrays and remove fields one by one. Since there seems to be three huge outputs, this will decrease the peak of memory usage to ~130% instead of 200%.

```
for k = 1:nsim
    ksim(:,:,k) = st(k).ksim;
end
st = rmfield(st , 'ksim');
for k = 1:nsim
    Msim(:,k) = st(k).Msim;
end
st = rmfield(st , 'Msim');
```

and so on.